# How to invert the green channel of an image in Python?

Tags: python, image, rgb

How do I invert one channel of an RGB image? In this case my image is a normal map for a 3D engine, saved in an image format like JPEG or TIFF, and I want to invert the green channel — that is, completely reverse the highs and lows in the green band.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this by installing and using [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html), which can work with most image formats (JPEG, PNG, TIFF, etc.).

```py
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ImageChops import invert

image = Image.open('test.tif')
red, green, blue = image.split()
image_with_inverted_green = Image.merge('RGB', (red, invert(green), blue))
image_with_inverted_green.save('test_inverted_green.tif')
```

After loading the image from your file, split into its channels with [`Image.split`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.split), invert the green channel/image with [`ImageChops.invert`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageChops.html#PIL.ImageChops.invert), and then join it together with the original red and blue bands into a new image with [`Image.merge`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.merge).

If using a format that's encoded in something other than RGB (such as PNG, which has an additional transparency channel), the image-opening line can be amended to:

```py
image = Image.open('test.png').convert('RGB')
```

Testing with this image:

[image: test.tif]

Produces this:

[image: test_with_inverted_green.tif]

(`ImageChops`, by the way, looks like a very odd term, but it's short for "image channel operations".)

Comment: I think that to check how many channels the image has it is possible to check the depth bits? That is usually 24bit are 3 channels, 32 are 4 channels (RGBA). I don't know much about GDP, but I think it can be controlled. In any case, I really appreciate this answer.

Comment: @NoobCat You can always check programmatically how many channels the image has, but it's not going to vary from image to image as long as you know what format you're saving your maps as. (I'm not familiar with GDP, other than gross domestic product.)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a numpy (or torch tensor) image - you can index on the green channel (assuming channels are your last dimension)

```
img[:, :, 1] = 255 - img[:, :, 1]
```

I am assuming by invert you want `0 -> 255` and `255 -> 0`

Comment: I added a detail to the question, which I had not specified, I apologize, the images in question are Normal maps for 3D graphic engines

Answer (score -3):

```
T(r) = L – 1 – r

L=256

L-1=255(Max)

r=Each pixel of the image

s=255-r

s= T(r) =255-r
```